# Laravel - Display information related to current user using junction table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

On my database I have three tables, like so:

users

```
+----+---------------+-----------+
| id | name          | role      |
+----+---------------+-----------+
|  3 | Pavel Chekov  | student   |
|  5 | Nyota Uhura   | student   |
|  6 | Leonard McCoy | professor |
+----+---------------+-----------+
```

subjects

```
+----+--------------------------+
| id | name                     |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | Relational Databases     |
|  3 | Accessibility            |
|  4 | Software Engineering     |
|  5 | Marketing and Business   |
+----+--------------------------+
```

P.S.: Each subject has a description on the table, not shown here.

users_subjects

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | subject_id |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       6 |          1 |
|  2 |       6 |          3 |
|  3 |       3 |          1 |
|  4 |       3 |          3 |
|  5 |       3 |          5 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

I must then display the subjects related to the user currently logged in (student or professor) in my template, like so:

```
<section class="section">

    <div class="tile is-ancestor">

      @foreach ($subjects as $subject)

      <div class="tile is-parent">
        <article class="tile is-child box">
          <p class="title">{{ $subject->name }}</p>
          <div class="content">
            <p>{{ $subject->description }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>

      @endforeach          

    </div>

</section>
```

A new tile will be created for each subject the user is associated with, filling the section. I want to display only the subjects related to the current user.

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: are you using eloquent

Comment: @afsal yes, it's the first time I'm using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you properly define your relations in your model:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function subjects(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

You should be able to simply retrieve the users subjects.

```
  @foreach ($user->subjects as $subject)

  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <article class="tile is-child box">
      <p class="title">{{ $subject->name }}</p>
      <div class="content">
        <p>{{ $subject->description }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>

  @endforeach
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Thanks. It's my first time using Eloquent and this section has been a bit more difficult to comprehend, but now it's clearer :)

Comment: No problem. Nice choice to start with Laravel!

Comment: thanks! Also, sorry to bother again, but reading the documentation and trying to implement I get the error "Trying to get property of non-object " when I try to define $user. Do you know what could cause that?